# Autosys ON ICE issues

Tags: autosys

I have a job_a and job_b. Job_b has dependency of job a. If job_a succeed then only job_b should start. I have a requirement to skip execution to these both jobs. So i have gone for to use Job ON ICE for both jobs. When I kept job_a on ice the job_b has been executed. Since it has matched on ice createria.

So how resolve this so that job_a and job_b should be skip for next execution.?

Comment: if you have kept both of them ON ICE, both should not run ! or you have kept only jobA ?

Comment: hi Piyush, I have kept first job_a on ice and then job_b on ice. then I see that job_b has been executed by job_a on ice.